# Hello World in Python on Apache

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I have been dabbling in Python over the past few weeks and thought it might be fun to mess around with writing some output in python on a website. Understanding that apache isn't the "ideal" environment to run python on the web, I would like to try to put some simple junk on a website.  Maybe connect to a database and write a very simple blog or something.

How do I make apache on my shared hosting account read my python file?  I have created hello.py with this content:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

print "Content-type: text/html"
print ""
print "Hello, World!"
```

and dropped this .htaccess:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

but when i try to visit domain.com/test.py I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, needed to make the file executable ;)

Comment: chmod +x hello.py ftw!

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned that you created **hello.py** and so you are visiting domain.com/**test.py** that seems wrong in that case after making **hello.py** executable using `sudo chmod +x hello.py` command you should visit ***domain.com/hello.py***